# Should one get in-state auto insurance if moving out-of-state for a year?

Tags: united-states, car-insurance, moving

My wife and I currently live in State A. She plans on moving to State B for a year (sad year!) for work reasons. "Her" car is registered in State A.

**Should she register her car or get auto insurance in State B?** Is there even a clear-cut right/wrong answer? Are there inherent pros/cons either way?

Recognizing that the primary question may be opinion-based, I'd appreciate discussion to inform my decision.

Comment: To some extent this will depend on the specific state's laws regarding residency and auto registration.  I think if a car is in CA for more than just a few weeks at a time CA wants you to have either CA plates and registration or a paid CA "out-of-state" registration.

Comment: Although you might get away with either option, legally you probably will not have a choice. Check with the target state's laws.